# Form submmited twice from MVC Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, form-submit

I am trying to explain why a user was able to submit the same form details twice. At first, I was thinking that the submit button was pushed twice, this may still be the case.

When I checked the results in the database, I can see the same information has been entered twice, but also the same datetime stamp has been entered, down to the second. Surely it takes at least another second to push submit again if this is the case.

In addition after the survey is inputted and saved the user is redirected to a different page.

Why does this happen?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InputResult(SurveyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Survey_Result InputResult = new Survey_Result();

        InputResult.SurveyStatusID = model.SurveyStatusID;
        InputResult.Q1DateCompleted = DateTime.Now;
        InputResult.Q2 = model.Q2;
        InputResult.Q3 = model.Q3;
        InputResult.Q10 = model.Q10;
        InputResult.Q11 = model.Q11;
        InputResult.Q11Other = model.Q11Other;
        InputResult.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        InputResult.AddedBy = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        _surveyService.AddSurvey(InputResult);
        _surveyService.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Survey", new { id = model.SurveyStatusID, feedback = "InputComplete" });
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Survey", new { id = model.SurveyStatusID, feedback = "InputError" });
}
```

Comment: It's pretty easy to press a button twice in 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine to me.  If you have access to the user, you could pop Fiddler on it to see if it is posting data twice.  If it doesn't happen all the time then its almost certainly user error IMHO.

If you don't have access to the client you could pop in a log entry on each post request or debug line if you are in a position to collect it on this server.

I had similar issues and client side javascript to disable the button on click did the trick for me.

Comment: It does seem to be down to user error, talking again to the user they said the page froze for a couple of seconds so they where 'clicking' again. It looks like client side javascript is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you need both AddSurvey and Save?

Remove save and retry.

Comment: Depends on his service class, but I would assume he does need it.